# JavaScript eventlistener

Tags: javascript

unfortunately I am stuck on a problem.

We have included this code via iFrame in our website https://kitarino.net/platz-anfrage

This is the code:

```
<div id="nemplads" data-lang="browser"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              (function() {
                var d = document,
                s = d.createElement('script');
                s.src = 'https://kitarinocockpit.nemborn.com/Script/NemPlads/preregister-v1.0.0.1.js';
                s.id = 'nemplads-script';
                s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                // window.addEventListener('success', (e) => {
                //   console.log(e.detail); // Original request arguments
                // });
                (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
              })();
            </script>
```

When someone has registered via the form, I would like to call the website https://kitarino.net/bestaetigung-bewerbung - so that the users gets a confirmation.

Can you help me with this? Unfortunately my attempts always fail. I don't know JavaScript well either and my colleague couldn't help me.

I had tried it with this:

```
// window.addEventListener('success', (e) => {
// console.log(e.detail); // Original request arguments
// loadedwindow(e) {window.open("https://www.google.com","_self")}
// });
```

I am grateful for any hint ;)

best, Alex

Comment: Which form ? you talk about a form and show us a script tag, that does not really make sense

Comment: Hey, if you open the website https://kitarino.net/platz-anfrage you will see the form.

We load it Form the script in an iFrame. It's provided to us by a service provider. The Form opens by clicking the green button on the right top „hier bewerben“

Comment: I won't go to the site, please put all the relevant code in the question

Comment: I have no more other code. The code above is the only code i got from our software to include in our website. But thanks for your time. Best, Alex

Comment: Are you asking how to do a redirect in javascript?

Comment: Yes, but only after the form has been completed and sent.

According to the service provider this part triggers a success response from the api.

`// window.addEventListener('success', (e) => {
//   console.log(e.detail); // Original request arguments
// });`

We should take the e.detail object and retrieve all the info we need.

My thought was, after the success-response came, to load a new page showing the confirmation-page from our website.

We can then include this page in our Analytics tracking.

Comment: sure, inside the callback you can do `window.location = "otherurl.html"` if you want, and you can also add paramters to this if you feel like it

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution:

```
const items = document.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
            for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
                const getParam = items[index].split("=");
                if (getParam[0] === 'id') {
                    document.location.href = 'https://www.kitarino.net/bestatigung-platzanfrage?id=' + decodeURIComponent(getParam[1]);
                    break;
```